# laravel 4.2: migration a string field with unique constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I would like to add a `dash_title` to my projects. The idea is to have a human readable ID. Which can be easily used in the url as well.

So I created my migration with:

```
artisan generate:migration add_dash_title_to_projects_table --fields="dash_title:string"
```

And add a `->unique()`  as specified in the [laravel 4.2 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema) to obtain:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('projects', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('dash_title')->unique();
    });
}
```

But I run into issue when I do `artisan migrate`:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                                      
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'projects_dash_title_unique' (SQL: alter table `projects` add unique projects_dash_title_unique(`dash_title`))  

[PDOException]                                                                                                 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'projects_dash_title_unique'
```

Seems like `dash_title` column was existing before the migration. But I'm sure it is not the case.

Anyway it has been created by the migrating command. But without `unique` flag. The `mysql` console says:

```
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| dash_title        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
```

I'm a bit lost. I really need to create a `unique` constraint to this field. How to?

Comment: ok... I got it. The error is due to migration of existing rows. so 1st create the field. Then migrate data with something logic. Then add the `unique` constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error was due to the update of current project rows.

So solution is:

1. create the new field: `dash_title`
2. migrate logically current rows
3. add the `unique` constraint

All can be done into the migration as:

```
public function up()
{
  // create the new field
  Schema::table('projects', function(Blueprint $table) {
     $table->string('dash_title');
  });

  // migrate existing rows
  $projects = Project::all();
  foreach ($projects as $p) {
    $p->dash_title = Helper::sanitize_title_with_dashes( $p->title );
    $p->save();
  }

  // add the unique constraint
  Schema::table('projects', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unique('dash_title');
  });
}
```

And to have a clean migration file we could add the following `down()` method:

```
public function down()
{
  Schema::table('projects', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn('dash_title');
    $table->dropColumn('projects_dash_title_unique');
   });
}
```